# Signing into custom web app with G-Suite account

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, authorization, google-signin, google-workspace

90% of my Google Apps Script/HTMLService web app is available to anonymous users, however user must be signed in with G-Suite account in order to access the remaining 10%.

Desired behavior is that if user is already logged in to G-Suite (e.g. read Gmail from that browser), the web app recognizes the user without prompting to log in again – as if you went to Google Calendar just after reading Gmail.  If user isn’t logged in yet – he needs to be prompted to log in using @my_g-suite.com account when accessing the restricted features.

My first try was two app approach: one published as “available to anyone including anonymous” and another “available to members of the my_g-suite.com”.  The problem with this approach is that 2nd app only shows log in screen if browser has no google identity.  If user is logged in to regular, non-g-suite gmail, strange google Driver error is shown instead of login prompt.  I [posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358253/prompting-for-credentials-when-accessing-standalone-htmlservice-webapp) about this a while ago, no solution.

So instead I implemented a sign-in button using [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).  Behavior I’m seeing is not what I expected:

1. If user is already signed in with *UserOne@my_g-suite.com* prior to accessing the app (e.g. looked at G-Suite email account), `Session.getActiveUser()` on server side returns correct user ID, however `googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail()` on client has nothing.
2. If user has not signed in with G-Suite ID using prior to accessing the app and then signs in using the Sign In button on web app, `googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail()` returns correct user ID, however ), `Session.getActiveUser()` on server side returns nothing.
3. If user has signs in using the button as *UserTwo@my_g-suite.com*, no other G-Suite app recognizes it.  So if user then signs in to *UserOne@my_g-suite.com* and comes back to the app, `Session.getActiveUser()` says it’s *UserOne@my_g-suite.com* and `googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail()` says it’s *UserTwo@my_g-suite.com*.  Two conflicting identities simultaneously.

How do I make sign-in into my app be 1) seamless with other G-Suite services rather than having completely separate, app-only 2nd identity and 2) restricted to *@my_g-suite.com*?

---

Following @TheMaster advice I tried this:

1. Created a Google Sites site "login.my_g-suite.com" which is only available to g-suite users and has a single page which says "you are logged in to g-suite"
2. In my web app which runs as "me" and is "available to everyone, even anonymous", I implemented a check if `Session.getActiveUser()` is g-suite user.  If not, I do `window.open("https://login.my_g-suite.com")` which opens log-in screen in the new tab as expected.
3. After user logs in, I reload web app. And here's the sad part:

   - If browser hasn't been used for non-G-Suite account (like regular Gmail) - all works great.  `Session.getActiveUser()` shows newly logged in user ID
   - BUT if that browser has been logged in to non-G-Suite account, `Session.getActiveUser()` has no idea about the fact that I just logged in G-Suite in another tab (even after reloading web app).  Which is back to square one.

Comparing this to Google's own apps, this behavior is not much different: e.g. if you read regular non-g-suite gmail, then go and log in to Google drive using G-Suite account, and then reload gmail - it doesn't take you to G-Suite Gmail automatically just because you logged in to G-Suite account on that browser.  You need to explicitly tell Gmail that you want to use G-Suite account by invoking active-account-selection menu (round avatar icon on the right upper corner).

Looks like no matter what approach I take, I hit the same wall: the need to tell stand-alone Google App Script which Google identity is current.  And I don't see any way of doing that.

---

What I stated above is no longer true due to recent change by Google.  (2) now results in Error 404 instead of login screen.

Sign-in issues which a few days ago were only affecting stand-alone Google App Script apps now are plaguing entire G-Suite.  Our volunteer first-responder organization got G-Suite mainly for the secure intranet site (members.my_g-suite.com) where we share internal protocols and documentation.  It's built on new Google Sites and Google Team Drive. Before Wednesday attempt to access members.my_g-suite.com used to take to G-Suite login screen.  Now it takes them to `"404. That’s an error. The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know."`. The only workaround is to force users to log out of personal Gmail each time before accessing G-Suite, which is not a reasonable request for a volunteer using personal device.  We feel like Google pulled the rug from under our feet.  The only hope is that this is a temporary change and they'll revert it to how it was in the beginning of the week.  We also confirmed that this change is not limited to our G-Suite.

Comment: Use only `googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail()`? Why are there two users using the same device?

Comment: As a unrelated question, Did just the meta name work `<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">`?

Comment: Re: "Use only googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail()":  it doesn't know that user is logged in already.  Bad experience - user can switch between gmail, calendar, even stackoverflow without need to enter username/password each time.  But for this one app user has to log in again.

Comment: Re: "Why are there two users using the same device": it's not uncommon for users to use same browser/device to access personal gmail and g-suite gmail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand question "Did just the meta name work".  To make Google Sign-In button work on my web app I had to add the meta tag you mentioned, actual button, on-click function, and also had to add javascript origin in config.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your web-app runs inside a iframe. You can force login by denying access to the web-app manually.

- `onload`, Check `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` server side and see if it matches your domain,

  - If it does, proceed to load your actual web-app
  - If not, just provide the information that the user needs to login to your gsuite to access.

You can also

- Proceed to open https://admin.google.com (or any url specific to your domain) in a another tab
- See whether it's open and use `setInterval` to check the other window.close property. When closed, reload your web-app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd like to ask for extra help here.  Are you suggesting two app approach where the functions intended for anonymous are in the first one, and when user tries to get to restricted functions - check Session.getActiveUser() before sending him to 2nd app? That works great if user isn't logged in to non-G-Suite account (like regular gmail).  Nice prompt to log in and all.  But if user read his personal email on that browser - "Google Drive: Sorry, unable to open the file at this time."   What code should I use and where to force login by denying access manually?

Comment: @Aud One app approach> Run as Me. Access: Anyony incl anone>Web-app opens, You check whether he's logged  into your domain using `Session.getActiveUser.getEmail()`. If not open a login window in another window. I  currently don't have access to GSuite(So can't test).

Comment: thanks - I described results of your suggested experiment as edit in the question.  Unfortunately Session.getActiveUser.getEmail() has no idea that I just logged in in another tab if that browser was used to log in to non-g-suite google account.

Comment: @Aud Force log them out of their current account.  https://superuser.com/a/696459  `https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https://login.my_g-suite.com` If your domain isn't on google, it'll probably throw 404. But, you can still use `https://accounts.google.com/Logout` > open that tab> wait 5s> replace that window with `https://login.my_g-suite.com` using `win2.location.href =https://login.my_g-suite.com`

Comment: Also, you can try directly redirecting from your Google site.